# How to use Hindi in Dreamweaver?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I want to write an HTML page in Hindi. I have tried searching for instructions on the web, including SO, but nothing seems to work. In my HTML editor and in the browser (Chrome) I see English even if I have set document language to Hindi. I also tried this CSS style:

```
@charset "utf-8";
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/lohitdevanagari.css);
p {
font-family: 'Lohit Devanagari', serif;
  }
```

Comment: this is really not enough information to constitute a question we can answer - is this *actually* about dreamweaver or just "an html page"? How are you trying to load the page (I certainly hope not using `file:///`)? What does the HTML that uses this CSS look like? Does the font import correctly according to the browser? etc.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Actually, the HTML page I am writing is not online yet, and I am trying to write the page for my blog on Blogger. Now I have solved the issue by finding some other way. Now I use transliteration tool provided by Google on Blogger.

Comment: That is not relevant for the purposes of asking a question: good questions on Stackoverflow about code that doesn't work comes with a [mcve], so just make a *new* HTML page with minimal code that shows off your problem.